# NHibernate stored procedure returns data from previous query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I use two stored procedures that return the data with the same structure (list of records of the same type).

I call my method Execute(ISession session) twice. First time for the first stored procedure (it returns correct list of 6 rows). Second time - for the second stored procedure (it returns list of 11 rows, but first 6 rows are from the first request that overwrite the correct rows).

I found
[Impact on NHibernate caching for searches with results including calculated value mapped as a formula (e.g. rank)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627707/impact-on-nhibernate-caching-for-searches-with-results-including-calculated-valu)

But I can't use it for IQuery

Any ideas or links how it can be fixed ?

```
public dynamic Execute(ISession session)
{
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery(QueryName)
        .SetCacheable(false)
        .SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Ignore)
        .SetReadOnly(true);
    var results = query.List<T>();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HQL of the two queries in question?

Comment: Sorry, there is no HQL, stored procedure is located on SQL server

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a stab at answering this, because I think I have a hunch of what's going on, and I want to set you on the right track.  I've made a lot of assumptions here, so please don't be too harsh on me if I was completely wrong with my guesses.

It feels like you're trying to use NHibernate as a tool to simply translate rows into objects.  Instead NHibernate is a tool that translates between your object oriented domain model and your relational database domain model.  It does a lot more that just turn rows into objects.  In particular, the NHibernate feature that you're tripping over here is how NHibernate ensures that within a single NHibernate session, a single row in the database which represents a single entity will correspond to a single instance of an object.  It uses its first-level cache to accomplish this.

Let's say you have two queries, QueryA and QueryB.  These queries have been constructed so that they each pull from separate tables, TableA and TableB, so really they represent separate entities.  However, the queries have also somehow been built so that the result look to NHibernate like the same entity.  If QueryA and QueryB happen to return some of the same ids, then NHibernate will combine them into the same instance, so you would see some of the results from QueryA repeated when you run QueryB.

So how do we fix it?

The quick and dirty fix would be to use different sessions for each of those two queries, or throw a `session.Clear()` in-between them.  The more appropriate fix would be to change these named queries so that they actually do return two different entities.

Comment: `session.Clear()` doesn't help.
I can't change the SP, but I can change the class that the data is mapped to. I made two classes with the same fields for mapping to every query of two. I understand, this is not the best solution, but it works.
Thank you for the ansewer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, in first place I resolved the problem with `session.Clear()` but this solution lead to another bug. I read the response of Daniel and this response I served to detect that the issue is in the stored procedure, the stored procedure did not return an unique identifier and this produced the error when I mapped the ID with nhibernate.